# SQL with one to many relation (three tables)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following structure of tables:

[image]

And I would like to have a query where I get all the items from table **T1** that are used in the related tables, showing all the fields from the related tables (**Related_Table_A** and **Related_Table_B**).

Notice that the fields in A and B are different.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Most people here want sample table data - and expected result - as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: Have you tried anything??

Comment: And what part of `INNER JOIN` do you not understand?

Comment: Sorry, next time I will use text instead!

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but this should do what you want.  Fill in the missing fields in the select:

```
Select
    t1.ID_WF,
    rtA.ID_Table_A,
    rtB.ID_table_B
    [ ... ]
From
    T1 t1
    full outer join Related_Table_A rtA on (t1.ID_WF = rtA.ID_WF)
    full outer join Related_Table_B rtB on (t1.ID_WF = rtB.ID_WF)
Where
    rtA.ID_Table_A IS NOT NULL
    or
    rtB.ID_Table_B IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.ID_WF AS T1_ID_WF, Related_Table_A.ID_WF AS Related_Table_A_ID_WF, 
Related_Table_A.Table_A_Field1, Related_Table_B.ID_WF AS Related_Table_B_ID_WF, 
Related_Table_B.Table_B_Field1, Related_Table_B.ID_Table_B, 
Related_Table_A.ID_Table_A
FROM (T1 INNER JOIN Related_Table_B ON T1.[ID_WF] = Related_Table_B.[ID_WF]) 
INNER JOIN Related_Table_A ON T1.[ID_WF] = Related_Table_A.[ID_WF];
```

Comment: Try this query:
SELECT T1.ID_WF, Related_Table_A.ID_WF, 
Related_Table_A.Table_A_Field1, Related_Table_B.ID_WF, 
Related_Table_B.Table_B_Field1, Related_Table_B.ID_Table_B, 
Related_Table_A.ID_Table_A
FROM T1 INNER JOIN Related_Table_B ON T1.ID_WF = Related_Table_B.ID_WF 
INNER JOIN Related_Table_A ON T1.ID_WF = Related_Table_A.ID_WF;

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT 
    t1.ID_WF, t2.ID_Table_a, t3.ID_Table_B,
    t1.T1_field1, t1.T1_field2, t3.Table_B_Field1,
    t2.Table_A_Field1, t2.Table_A_Field2, t2.Table_A_Field3
FROM t1
    LEFT JOIN Related_Table_A t2
    ON t1.ID_WF = t2.ID_WF
    LEFT JOIN Related_Table_B t3
    ON t1.ID_WF = t3.ID_WF
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but I got a synthax error: (I updated the names for easier reading)
SELECT t1.ID_WF, t1.T1_field1, t1.T1_field2, tA.ID_Table_A, tA.Table_A_Field1, tA.Table_A_Field2, tA.Table_A_Field3
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN tA 
ON t1.ID_WF = tA.ID_WF
LEFT JOIN tB 
ON t1.ID_WF = tA.ID_WF;

Comment: LEFT JOIN tA ON t1.ID_WF = tA.ID_WF 
LEFT JOIN tB ON t1.ID_WF = tB.ID_WF;